# create ancestor matrix for binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

```
     1
   /  \
  2    3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
```

for the given binary tree we need to create a matrix a[7][7] 
satisfying the ancestor property  like a[2][1]=1 since 1 is an ancestor of 2 ....

i solved it by using extra space an array ...the solution i came up is

```
int a[n][n]={0};
void updatematrix(int a[][n],struct node *root,int temp[],int index){

if(root == NULL)
  return ;
int i;

for(i=0;i< index;i++)
  a[root->data][temp[i]]=1;
temp[index]=root->data;

updatematrix(a,root->left,temp,index+1);
updatematrix(a,root->right,temp,index+1);
}
```

is there any mistake in my solution ?
can we do this inplace ???(i mean without using the  temp array )

Comment: I guess that in your code you need to replace the first occurence of `arr` by `a`, and replace the second occurrence of `arr` by `temp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` contains the path from root to current node, i.e. the set of nodes visited while walking down the tree to arrive at the current node.

If you have a parent pointer in each node (but I guess not), you can follow those pointers and walk up the tree to traverse the same set of nodes as `temp`. But this uses more memory.

You can also walk down the tree several times (pseudocode):

```
def updatematrix(a,node):
  if node is null: return
  walkDown(a.data,node.left)
  walkDown(a.data,node.right)
  updatematrix(a,node.left)
  updatematrix(a,node.right)

def walkDown(data,node):
  if node is null: return
  a[node][data] = 1
  walkDown(data,node.left)
  walkDown(data,node.right)
```

Same complexity, but the pattern of memory access looks less cache friendly.