# Create Ancestor Matrix from given Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

The question is, given a Ancestor Matrix, as a bitmap of 1s and 0s, to construct the corresponding Binary Tree. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do it? I found a solution at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664257/create-ancestor-matrix-for-binary-tree), but the line `a[root->data][temp[i]]=1` seems wrong, there is no binding that the nodes will contain data 1 to n. It may contain, say 2000, in which case, there will be no `a[2000][some_column]`, since there are only 7 nodes, hence 7 rows and columns in the matrix.

Comment: If you have a node labeled `2000` the matrix has to be at least `2000 x 2000`. That's how an ancestor matrix works afaik. How else do you want to store information about node 2000 in a matrix?

Comment: I can easily have 3 nodes, with 5 being the root, 2000 being its right-child, and 1 its left-child.

Comment: Yes, but that's your English description. How are you going to store that in a matrix?

Comment: The matrix is `n*n`, `n` being the number of nodes. There is an extra top row and extra left column for denoting the node values. Have a look at http://www.ritambhara.in/build-binary-tree-from-ancestor-matrics/.

Comment: So remap the labels to 0 - n-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Normalize your node values such that they are all from 1 to `n`. If you have nodes `1, 2, 5000` for example, make them `1, 2, 3`. You can do this by sorting or hashing your labels and keeping something like `normalized[i] = normalized value of node i`. `normalized` can be a map / hash table if you have very large labels or even text labels.
2. You might be able to use a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) for this, implementable with a hash table or a set: keep a hash table of hash tables. `H[x]` stores another hash table that stores your `y` values. So if in a naive matrix solution you had `a[2000][5000] = 1`, you would use `H.get(2000)` => returns a hash table `H'` of values stored on the 2000th row => `H'.get(5000)` => returns the value you want.

Comment: @Cupidvogel - his question is the reverse of what you're asking: he asked how to build the matrix from the tree, you're asking about building the tree from the matrix. That said, his solution does seem correct for what he was trying to do.

Comment: No no, I meant to do the same. Made a mistake while typing the question.

Comment: @Cupidvogel then yes, I think it is, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Hi IVlad, can you please explain how the algorithm works? While calling the function initially, should index be 0, or 1?

Comment: Ivlad, please explain the algo!

Comment: @Cupidvogel - you mean the algorithm in the question you linked to? It seems rather straightforward, you just descend the tree keeping the nodes you visited in a temporary array (think of it like the recursion stack). At a certain node `k` (`root->data` in that code), you know the values / nodes in that temp array / stack are the ancestors of `k` so you just fill in the matrix accordingly. Is there anything in particular you don't understand about it?

Comment: Should I initially call the function with index as 0, or 1?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - index as 0, because otherwise you'd be using an uninitialized value for the root.